# Recursive function that returns the number of possible combinations

Tags: arrays, math, recursion

I had an interview and was asked a question that I'd like to understand the solution.

## The Question

Create a recursive function that returns the number of possible combinations of arrays of a given length that could be made from an array of non-repeating consecutive integers.

f(array, length) = Combinations

### Example 1

- array = [0,1,2,3]
- length = 2
- Combinations = 10 (all combinations: [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [2,2] [2,3] [3,3])
- Note that [0,0] is allowed but [1,0] is not because [0,1] is defined

### Example 2

- array = [0,1]
- length = 3
- Combinations = 4 (all combinations: [0,0,0] [0,0,1] [0,1,1] [1,1,1])

One "hint" was offered. The interviewer said the array itself shouldn't matter; the length was all that was needed.

Comment: Do you not understand the question or the solution? Do you know how recursion works?  The point of questions like this is not to get "the right answer" but to think about how you would solve a problem.  IF you don;t understand recursion, then the solution won't make sense to you either.

Comment: @DStanley - I do actually understand recursion, although it added to the complexity. What I had the most trouble understanding was how you would use recursion to accomplish the desired result. My gut instinct was to use a series of really ugly loops. It just completely stumped me.

Comment: There's nothing in your question that explains why [2,1] and [1,0,0] aren't valid combinations.

Comment: @MattTimmermans If [1,0] is not allowed because [0,1] is defined then I guess [2,1] isn't because [1,2] is defined, same with [1,0,0] and [0,1,0] as [0,0,1] is defined.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192670/n-unlabelled-balls-in-m-labeled-buckets

Comment: Also nothing to say why [0,2] is not a solution because the criternion of "non-consecutive" applies to the input array only

Comment: @meowgoesthedog - Thanks, updated the question. You're absolutely correct, those values were missing

Comment: Even though the question asks for "combinations", the word "multiset" would probably be more accurate. The point of the hint is that the fact that the input array consists of consecutive elements isn't relevant, but the *length* of that array is relevant. In effect, you are being asked to find a recursive formula for `f(n,k)` = the number of `k`-element multisets of an `n` element set.

Comment: PhD?  You can understand what combinations and permutations are without a doctorate.  I think a lack in that area is fatal, much more damaging than the lack of a degree.

Comment: I think a fair response to them would be "Why would you write a 'recursive function' when the value you want can be computed directly?". Just because you're told to do X doesn't mean that X is the best way to solve a problem.

Comment: @duffymo - That comment is totally unnecessary, we're all learning every day. I didn't put that in the question to make myself feel better about failing the interview, it was a hint at which company I was screening with. The whole point of my posting this is to learn.

Comment: I wasn't trying to make you feel bad.  I'm am correcting your notion that you need a Ph.D. to work at that company because they asked about combinations and recursions.  I only meant to point out that neither concept required advanced education.  If you didn't do well on the interview, it's not because you don't have a Ph.D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm can be expressed recursively because the solution can be expressed in terms of solutions for smaller inputs. "Smaller" here has two meanings:

- A subset of the array; specifically the sub-array after the current element index
- Solutions for smaller length; these can be added together to give the solution for length + 1

Stopping conditions:

- When the array size `A = 1` - only one combination can be generated
- When the length `L = 1` - number of combinations = number of elements in array

The fully recursive procedure is a surprisingly simple one-liner:

```
return [recursive call to rest of array, same length] + 
       [recursive call to same array, length - 1]
```

This is called *dynamic programming*.

Code:

```
int F(int A, int L)
{
    if (A <= 1) return 1;
    if (L <= 1) return A;
    return F(A - 1, L) + F(A, L - 1);
}
```

Tests:

- `F(4, 2) = 10`
- `F(2, 3) = 4`
- `F(3, 5) = 21` (trace it with pen-and-paper to see for yourself)

---

EDIT: I've given an elegant and simple solution, but I perhaps haven't explained it as well as @RoryDaulton. Consider giving his answer credit too.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes sense but even seeing it written out I can barely wrap my head around it. It will be fun to dig deeper into this stuff. Blowing a phone screen and not having the problem explained was killing me.

Answer (score 2):

You do not give a target language and you do not say just how much help you want. So I'll give the overall idea of an algorithm that should be simple to code if you know recursion in a certain language. Ask if you want more code in Python, my current preferred language.

You know you need to do recursion, and you have two things you could recurse on: the length of the given array or the length of the desired arrays. Let's recurse on the second, and let's say the given array is `[0, 1, ..., n-1]` since you know that the actual contents are irrelevant.

If the desired length `r` is `1` you know there are only `n` desired arrays, namely `[0]`, `[1]`, ..., `[n-1]`. So there is the base case for your recursion.

If you have a "combination" of length `r-1`, how can that be expanded to length `r` and keep the requirements? Look at the last element in the array of length `r-1`--let's call it `k`. The next element cannot be less than that, so all the possible arrays extended to length `r` are the `r-1` array appended with `k', 'k+1`, ..., `n-1`. Those are `n-k` arrays of length `r`.

Is it clear how to code that? Note that you do not need to keep all the arrays of length `r-1`, you only need the count of how many arrays there are that end with the element `0` or `1` or ... `n-1`. That makes it convenient to code--not much memory is needed. In fact, things can be reduced further--I'll leave that to you.

Note that the interviewer probably did not want the code, he wanted your thought-process leading to the code to see the way you think. This is one way to think the problem through.

Comment: Thanks Rory, this is very helpful. I appreciate the time you took to break down the thought process.